# Get content of public Google Doc in text/plain format with drive.files.export (Drive API v3) + API key

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

I need to load content of my public Google Doc in a web page in text/plain format.

I've found API 'drive.files.export' that seems to do exactly what I need.

```
https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/export

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/drive/drive/v3/drive.files.export
```

Here is a link to a test file I've created:

```
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1L5XSb0mR4VrVagQLRkvdg9aSMjRgWdq0L6d7TK8Vslo
```

So file ID is:

```
1L5XSb0mR4VrVagQLRkvdg9aSMjRgWdq0L6d7TK8Vslo
```

I've also created a project on Google Developers Console, enabled Drive API and obtained API key:

```
AIzaSyCeVVoW3NbuoVrmW_pa5HtVSG2rxQyEDXs
```

By reading 'API Client Library for JavaScript' documentation I assume I don't need 'OAuth 2.0' authentication because I'm not going to access any user private data. So API key should be suficiente. The idea is that user doesn't have to do any authorization.

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/authentication

So I came up with this simple code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function makeRequest() {
    var request = gapi.client.drive.files.export({
        'fileId': '1L5XSb0mR4VrVagQLRkvdg9aSMjRgWdq0L6d7TK8Vslo',
        'mimeType': 'text/plain'
    });

    request.then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }, function(err) {
        console.log('Error');
        console.log(err.result.error);
    });
}

function init() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey('AIzaSyCeVVoW3NbuoVrmW_pa5HtVSG2rxQyEDXs');
    gapi.client.load('drive', 'v3').then(makeRequest);
}

</script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=init"></script>
```

But it is not working. I always get this response:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "internalError",
    "message": "Internal Error"
   }
  ],
  "code": 500,
  "message": "Internal Error"
 }
}
```

But when I try 'drive.files.get' API (https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/drive/drive/v3/drive.files.get) just for testing purposes with mentioned file ID and API key I get proper response from the API:

```
{
 "kind": "drive#file",
 "id": "1L5XSb0mR4VrVagQLRkvdg9aSMjRgWdq0L6d7TK8Vslo",
 "name": "test",
 "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.document"
}
```

Is it a bug of drive.files.export API and that's why it is not working with combination API key + public file or I have missed something and I am doing something wrong here?

I'll be really happy for any help.

Comment: In case anyone runs into this issue there is an open bug for it in Google  
apps-api-issues page (goo.gl/bmZQ4J) Recommendation is to use Drive v2 API

Comment: v2 API doesn't work either. You asked this question in 2016 and I have seen v3 work in 2017. Google has screwed it up again in 2018. This API and the automated tests for it are a disaster.

Answer (score 1):

Error 500 is a server error. See [ON_SERVER_ERROR](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/reference/1.20.0/com/google/api/client/http/HttpBackOffUnsuccessfulResponseHandler.BackOffRequired#ON_SERVER_ERROR). What you can do about this kind of error is to implement an [exponential backoff](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/backoff?hl=en) to fire the request again.

> Back-off required implementation which its isRequired(HttpResponse) returns true if a server error occurred (5xx).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've done some research and found also some info about exponential backoff inside Drive REST API [link](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#500_backend_error) But the thing is that I never get response from the server with data I'm requesting. It always return mentioned error so just sending the request periodically after some time will not probably help because all requests will fail.